# Use associative arrays with preg_replace

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace, associative

In the documentation for preg_replace it says you can use indexed arrays to replace multiple strings.  I would like to do this with associative arrays, but it seems to not work.

Does anyone know if this indeed does not work?

Comment: See this link [Pre_REPLACE with Asscoiate Array][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979011/use-preg-replace-to-replace-whole-words-using-associative-array

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you want to do this on keys or the keys and values or just retain the keys and process the values? Whichever the case, [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php), [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [`array_values()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) can achieve this in combination.

**On the keys:**

```
$keys = array_keys($input);
$values = array_values($input);
$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $keys);
$output = array_combine($result, $values);
```

**On the keys and values:**

```
$keys = array_keys($input);
$values = array_values($input);
$newKeys = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $keys);
$newValues = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $values);
$output = array_combine($newKeys, $newValues);
```

**On the values retaining keys:**

```
$keys = array_keys($input);
$values = array_values($input);
$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $values);
$output = array_combine($keys, $result);
```

All of these assume a function something like:

```
function regex_replace(array $input, $pattern, $replacement) {
  ...
  return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, what you want is:

```
$patterns = array_keys($input);
$replacements = array_values($input);
$output = preg_replace($patterns,$replacements,$string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Spent quite bit of time on this so will add my answer

```
$str = "CT is right next to NY";

$list = array('CT'=>'connenticut', 'NY'=>'New York', 'ME' => 'Maine');
$list = get_json();

$pattern = array_keys($list);
$replacement = array_values($list);

foreach ($pattern as $key => $value) {
    $pattern[$key] = '/\b'.$value.'\b/i';
}

$new_str = preg_replace( $pattern,$replacement,  $str);
```

Make sure you use /delimiters/ for regex pattern matching. \b is for word boundary.