# use preg_replace to replace whole words using associative array

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, associative-array, str-replace

I have this replacement array named `$initialdata` :

```
array ($initialdata)
  'd' => string '1.40' (length=4)
  'a' => string '1.67' (length=4)
  'vi' => string '0' (length=1)
  't' => string '?' (length=1)
```

Then I have this string :

```
$str =  "-(vi + sqrt(2*a*d + vi^2))/a)";
```

When I do :

```
str_replace(array_keys($initialdata),array_values($initialdata),$str);
```

I Get :

```
-(0 + sqr?(2*1.67*1.40 + 0^2))/1.67)
```

What happened was that the "t" of the "sqrt" was replaced by the value of "t" on my `$initialdata` array. I know that this happens because I'm using `str_replace`, and I need to match whole words using `preg_replace`, however I never saw any implementation of `preg_replace` using associative arrays to match any whole word. How can this be achieved if possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regex, `\b` are the word boundaries. This should work:

```
$data = array(
  '/d/' => '1.40',
  '/a/' => '1.67',
  '/vi/' => '0',
  '/\bt\b/' => '?'
);

$result = preg_replace(array_keys($data), array_values($data), $str);
```